# OpenVINO OpenCV Raspberry Pi & Arduino Serial Communication Script Slow

Tags: opencv, arduino, serial-communication

Hello I was wondering what the problem was when I ran this script. It runs and freezes when it sees someone and then, after a while, you can use the joysticks to move the neck and eyes also.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the serial communication part that is messing it up.

'Raspberry Pi Code'

```
#import libraries
import cv2
import time
import numpy
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from functools import partial
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

# Load the face detection model
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('/home/pi/buildnew/face-detection-adas-0001.xml', '/home/pi/buildnew/face-detection-adas-0001.bin')


# Specify target device
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_MYRIAD)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 28800)
    ser.flush()

# Misc vars
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
frameWidth = 320
frameHeight = 240


#Start and warm iup camera
camera = PiCamera()
camera.rotation = 180
camera.resolution = (320,240)
camera.framerate = 35
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320,240))
time.sleep(0.1)

"""
# USBcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#Get the camera data:
def capProperties():
print("[info] W, H, FPS")
print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

capProperties()
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, frameWidth)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, frameHeight)
"""

#time the frame rate....
start = time.time()
frames = 0

def classify_frame(net, inputQueue, outputQueue):
#loop the function
    while True:
        if not inputQueue.empty():
            # grab the frame from camera and create a blob
            frame = inputQueue.get()
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300))

            blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, size=(300, 300), ddepth=cv2.CV_8U)
            net.setInput(blob)
            out = net.forward()

#Outputting detections
            outputQueue.put(out)

#initializing queue and fps
inputQueue = Queue(maxsize=1)
outputQueue = Queue(maxsize=1)
out = None

# constructing arg child process
print("[INFO] starting process...")
p = Process(target=classify_frame, args=(net,inputQueue,outputQueue,))
p.daemon = True
p.start()
print("[INFO] starting capture...")
face_count = 0

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="rgb", use_video_port=True):
#while(True):#USBcam
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    #ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = frame.array

    #if statement to check if queue empty or not
    if inputQueue.empty():
        inputQueue.put(frame)
    if not outputQueue.empty():
        out = outputQueue.get()


#if statement to check if out of detection
    if out is not None:
        #loop and draw the detections
        for detection in out.reshape(-1, 7):

            confidence = float(detection[2])

            xmin = int(detection[3] * frame.shape[1])
            ymin = int(detection[4] * frame.shape[0])
            xmax = int(detection[5] * frame.shape[1])
            ymax = int(detection[6] * frame.shape[0])

            if confidence > 0.75:
                face_count += 1
                print(face_count)
                #placing border around face
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), color=(230, 0, 0))

                #labeling border and serial code
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin-1, ymin-1),\
                (xmin+60, ymin-10), (0,255,255), -1)
                #labeltext
                cv2.putText(frame,'Face'+ str(face_count) +':' + str(round(confidence,2)),\
                (xmin,ymin-2), font, 0.3,(0,0,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
                string='{0:d}:{1:d}'.format((xmax-xmin//2),(ymax-ymin//2))
                print(string)
                ser.write(string.encode('utf-8'))
                line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
                print(string)
     

# Display the resulting frame
    cv2.namedWindow('frame',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow('frame',frameWidth,frameHeight)
    newframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow('frame',newframe)
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    frames+=1

#press q to stop script
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

#tracks fps
end = time.time()
seconds = end-start
fps = frames/seconds
print("Average FPS: "+str(fps))

#end the script
#cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

'Arduino Code'

```
 //includes

#include<AccelStepper.h>
#include<Servo.h>
#include<math.h>

         //motor declarations

const int tiltdir = 8; // set tilt direction control to digital pin 8
const int tiltpulse = 9; // set tilt pulse control to digitial pin 9

const int pandir = 6; // set pan direction control to digital pin 6
const int panpulse = 7; // set pan pulse control to digital pin 7

const int joyH = 3;        //set joystick 1 axis 1 to analog pin 3
const int joyV = 4;        //set joystick 1 axis 2 to analog pin 4
const int joy2H = 1;       //set joystick 2 axis 1 to analog pin 1
const int joy2V = 2;       //set joystick 2 axis 2 to analog pin 2

AccelStepper pan = AccelStepper(1, panpulse, pandir); // initialize pan stepper on digital pins 8-11
AccelStepper tilt = AccelStepper(1, tiltpulse, tiltdir); // initialize pan stepper on digital pins 8-11

Servo LR;                  //initialize left/right servo
Servo UD;                  //initializer up/down servo

int X;
int Y;
float Xdist; long int Xdist2;
float Ydist; long int Ydist2;
float h; int dirX; int dirY;
int posh;                             //position variable 1 for joystick 1
int posv;                             //position variable 2 for joystick 1
int eyeh;                             //position variable 1 for joystick 2
int eyev;                             //position variable 2 for joystick 2
int ipan;                             //pan iteration to keep track of pan position
int itilt;                            //tilt iteration to keep track of tilt position
int eyepan;                           //pan iteration for eye servo
int eyetilt;                          //tilt iteration for eye servo
int panpos = 0;                      //initialize pan position to be 50 (out of 100)
int tiltpos = 0;                     //initialize tilt position to be 30 (out of 60)
int eyepos = 30;
float eyeposrad;
int eyetiltpos = 30;
float eyetiltposrad;
String coordinates;

         //variable declarations


void setup() {
       //set motor speeds

 pan.setMaxSpeed(1000); // Set the motor movement values
 pan.setAcceleration(1000);
 tilt.setMaxSpeed(1000); // Set the motor movement values
 tilt.setAcceleration(500);

  //attach servo pins

 LR.attach(12);             //attach left/right servo to pin 12
 UD.attach(13);             //attach up/down servo to pin 13

  //open serial port

Serial.begin(28800);           //start serial terminal

}

void loop() {

 ipan = 0;                     //reset neck movement indicators
 itilt = 0;

 if (pan.isRunning() != true && tilt.isRunning() != true) {

  posh = analogRead(joyH);          //read joystick position
  posv = analogRead(joyV);
  eyeh = analogRead(joy2H);        //read joystick position
  eyev = analogRead(joy2V);

Serial.print(posh);
Serial.print("  ");
Serial.print(posv);
Serial.print("     ");
Serial.print(eyeh);
Serial.print(" ");
Serial.print(eyev);

Serial.print(" ");
Serial.println(panpos);

 if ((400 > posh > 600) || (400 > posv > 600) || (600 < eyeh < 400) || (400 > eyev > 600)) {
 

  if (posh < 400 ){                //determine direction of joystick
    panpos = panpos - 3;                     //set pan direction based on joystick
   }
   
   else if (posh > 600 ){
     panpos = panpos + 3;
   }

  if (posv < 400 ){              //determine direction of joystick
    tiltpos = tiltpos - 3;                  //set tilt direction based on joystick
  }
  else if (posv > 600 ){
    tiltpos = tiltpos + 3;
  }  

  if (panpos < -60){               // account for lower neck pan position limit
     ipan = 0;
     panpos = -60;
   }
   else if (panpos > 60){        // account for upper neck pan position limit
     ipan = 0;
     panpos = 60;
   }  

   if (tiltpos < -30){             // account for lower neck tilt position limits
     itilt = 0;
     tiltpos = -30;
   }
   else if (tiltpos > 30){      // account for upper neck tilt position limits
     tiltpos = 30;
   }

    pan.moveTo(panpos);                          //set neck pan target position
    tilt.moveTo(tiltpos);                        //set neck tilt target position

   
  if (eyeh < 400 ){                //determine direction of joystick
    eyepos = eyepos - 3;
  }
   else if (eyeh > 600 ){
     eyepos = eyepos + 3;
   }    
   
  if (eyev < 400 ){                //determine direction of joystick
    eyetiltpos = eyetiltpos - 3;
  }
  else if (eyev > 600 ){
    eyetiltpos = eyetiltpos + 3;
  }
 
   if (eyepos > 60) {          //determine if at eye pan upper limit
     eyepos = 60;                   //account for eye pan upper limit
   }
   if (eyepos < 0) {
     eyepos = 0;                   //account for eye pan lower limit
   }
   if (eyetiltpos < 0) {
     eyetiltpos = 0;         //account for eye tilt lower limit
   }
   if (eyetiltpos > 60) {
     eyetiltpos = 60;         //account for eye tilt lower limit
   }


 }
 
  else  if (Serial.available()>0){

   while (Serial.available()){                                //clear serial buffer of data
    String coordinates = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');          //read serial port for position data
   // Serial.print("Data received: ");
   
                                   //calculate eye movement necessary

   String xval = getValue(coordinates, ':', 0);
   String yval = getValue(coordinates, ':', 1);
   
   
   X = xval.toInt();
   Y = yval.toInt();
   dirX = 1;
   dirY = 1;
   }

   Xdist = -1*(160 - X);
   if (Xdist < 0){
    Xdist = Xdist * -1;
    dirX = -1;
    }
   Ydist = -1*(120 - Y);
   if (Ydist < 0 ){
    Ydist = Ydist * -1;
    dirY = -1;
    }

   h = sqrt(sq(Xdist) +sq(Ydist));
   dirY = dirY * -1;

   eyeposrad = acos((Xdist/h));
   eyepan = dirX * eyeposrad * (180/PI);
   eyepos = eyepos + eyepan;
   eyetiltposrad = acos(Ydist/h);
   eyetilt = dirY * eyetiltposrad * (180/PI);
   eyetiltpos = eyetiltpos + eyetilt;

   //Serial.print("  X: ");
   //Serial.print(Xdist*dirX);
   //Serial.print("  Y: ");
   //Serial.print(Ydist*dirY);
   //Serial.print("  h: ");
   //Serial.print(h);
   //Serial.print(" acos(x/h): ");
   //Serial.print(eyepos);
   //Serial.println();
 }



 

 
 
                                   
 pan.run();                       //move neck pan motor
 tilt.run();                      //move neck tilt motor
 LR.write(eyepos);                //move eye pan servo
 UD.write(eyetiltpos);            //move eye tilt servo

 



  //sensor detects distance when motors not moving and image centered

}
//}
}

String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)       //
{
    int found = 0;
    int strIndex[] = { 0, -1 };
    int maxIndex = data.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex && found <= index; i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex) {
            found++;
            strIndex[0] = strIndex[1] + 1;
            strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
        }
    }
    return found > index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}
```